# Load configuration file from stream instead of file

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config, app-config

I use OpenMappedExeConfiguration with ExeConfigurationFileMap to load configuration files. Their overloads suggest that they only work with filenames. Is there a way to load a configuration file from a stream?

Background: I want to load configuration files that are stored as embedded resources. There is no file representation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.** The problem is that this class itself do not read the configuration. The file path itself is eventually used by the `Configuration` class to load the configuration, and this class actually wants a physical path.

I think the only solution is to store the file to a temporary path and read it from there.

Comment: An excerpt of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx illustrates the need for a "physical" path: “The Configuration class instance represents the merged view of the configuration settings from all of the configuration files that apply to a specific physical entity”

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.** If your application is allowed to change files in the application folder - update `*.config` file,  by file IO operations or by doing "section `update`/`save`/`refresh`" . There is straight forward logic in this solution - want to have remote configuration? Get it from remote, update local and have it.

Sample: let say you have stored your wcf section's group (`<bindings>`, `<behaviors>`.. etc) in the file `wcfsections.test.config` (of course any remote source is possible) and want to "overload" conf file configuration. Then configration update/save/refresh code looks like:

```
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationSectionCollection sections = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config).Sections;
        sections.Clear();

        string fileName = ((GeneralSettings)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("generalSettings")).AppConfigServiceModelSectionFile;

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        var xmlGroup = (from x in doc.Descendants("system.serviceModel") select x).FirstOrDefault();

        string[] sectionsInUpdateOrder = { "bindings", "comContracts", "behaviors", "extensions", "services", "serviceHostingEnvironment", "client", "diagnostics" };
        foreach (string key in sectionsInUpdateOrder)
        {
            var e = (from x in xmlGroup.Elements(key) select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (e != null)
            {
                ConfigurationSection currentSection = sections[e.Name.LocalName];
                string xml = e.ToString();
                currentSection.SectionInformation.SetRawXml(xml);
            }
        }
        config.Save();
        foreach (string key in sectionsInUpdateOrder)
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("system.serviceModel/" + key);
```

Note: the updates order is important for wcf validation subsystem. If you update it in wrong order, you can get validation exceptions.